# Prevent NUMBER_GROUPING of integers in Django Template

Tags: django, templates, internationalization, number-formatting

Django has a nice feature to add thousands separators to integers in templates automatically, by setting NUMBER_GROUPING=True. The problem is that for some integers (for instance 'year') you do not want decimal grouping. Somehow I can't find a filter or something else that prevents Django from adding thousands separators to my integers.

Does anyone know what I should do to exclude certain integers from being processed by the NUMBER_GROUPING process, without disabling this functionality for other integers?

Wout

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `NUMBER_GROUPING` setting is part of django's format localization functionality. To get rid of it in a template try `{{ value|unlocalize }}`. You'll also need to `{% load l10n %}` beforehand. This also seems to require django 1.3.

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/#topic-l10n-templates) for more info.